# How to remove Next.js chunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working Next.js, Reactjs project. I want to remove chunk js files from `_next/static/chunks` folder because Lighthouse showing remove unused JS. Is this possible to remove all chunk files.

Comment: May I ask, why would you want to do that?

Comment: I guess those are the compiled js files created with nextjs magic and you cant remove them

Comment: @OrAssayag because in Lighthouse it is showing remove unused JS.

Comment: Rather than removing those chunks you should look into ways of optimising them, like code splitting and unused code elimination. For more details check: https://web.dev/unused-javascript/#how-to-remove-unused-javascript.

Comment: Did you come up with a solution to this? I have the same problem. Nextjs automatically adds rehydration scripts which in my case are not needed (output could be pure html)

Comment: @noctonura No We can't remove the chunks instead try to optimise your chunks using Dynamic Imports. Also you can use **webpack chunk analyzer** to analyse your chunks.

Answer (score 3):

These chunks are for converting your `jsx` or `tsx` files from `js` to `html`.

That's the whole concept of single-page applications (SPAs). Fast refreshing and state management are all controlled by those chunks.

Comment: Does this also apply to static pages generated by Next.js ?